# How to glue to cardboard without warping or curling

Tags: game-development, custom-game-pieces

I enjoy designing board games but have very little budget for it.  I usually begin with plain paper as I create the first prototype.  It is hard to use flimsy paper for a board game board and I want to create a cardboard-backed game board.  Ideally it will be free, or very inexpensive.

I have a cardboard, fold-up game board from an old Sorry set that I would like to repurpose for a new project.  I plan to print sheets of paper with the new game board image and then adhere them over the Sorry board.

Any time I've tried using cardboard and gluing paper to it, though, it curls up and warps as it dries.  How can I glue plain printer paper to a 18" square card board game board without it warping?  Is there a certain type of glue, or a gluing/drying technique that would help?

Comment: Do you have to use glue? Or would clear tape work?

Comment: Have you tried putting something heavy on it as it dries, to keep it flat?

Comment: When making small game components (for example, Settlers of Catan hexagons), I will often print my designs on full-sheet mailing labels, then stick them to foam board and cut them out.  Maybe you could use a few of these big labels stuck to your "Sorry" board.